# Can a perfect square N be composed by only 0 and 1? Where N's prime factor are only 3 and 7.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers, decimal-expansion

I would like to know if someone knows how to prove that there are no perfect square composed only by zeros and ones in their decimal representation whose prime factors are only 3 and 7 (so of the form $N=3^{2a}\cdot 7^{2b}$). (For example, numbers like 10101001, 1001010100001,...)

using Mathematica with this code:

`Select[Range[1, 10000000],  Complement[IntegerDigits[#^2], {1, 0}] == {} &]`

I have verified that there are no such perfect square numbers below $10^{14}$

In my particular case I know that the only prime numbers which divides this N are 3 and 7. So we know that N is a perfect square composed only by zeros and ones and it's of the form $3^{2a}\cdot 7^{2b}$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$. Going further I note that if such N exists, then it's of the form $N=9^{10t}\cdot 49^{2r}$ or $N=9^{10t+5}\cdot 49^{2r+1}$for some $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$.

I would like to show that such N can not exists.

Comment: We can slightly generalize the question allowing perfect powers. We should be able to apply brute force easily upto about $30$ digits. You can save a lot of time by generating only the possible numbers and not loop over all positive integers.

Comment: Upto $27$ digits, the only perfect powers occuring are the powers of ten. However, I have no idea for a general proof (even with the given restrictions)

Comment: Yeah, that's true! But still.. I've no idea how to prove this. Although seems very clear

Comment: Note that $N$ cannot end in $0$, since then it would have $5$ as a prime factor; so it must end in $1$. Next, $N$ cannot end in $11$, since such numbers are $\equiv 3 \bmod 4$ and cannot be squares; so $N$ ends in $01$. This tells you that $\sqrt{N}$ ends either in $01$ or $51$. I haven't pushed this, but you might be able to work along these lines to show that there is no such $N$.

Comment: sqrt(n) could also end in 49 or 99

Comment: N must end in 001, because $101 \equiv 5 \mod 8$ but $m^{2}=N\not\equiv 5 \mod 8$ because there are no perfect squares that are congruent to 5 mod 8. Furthermore, in my particular case, since $9\mid N$ we know that the number of ones is a multiple of 9.